# Quantify likelihoods information within a Bayesian framewrok

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Suppose that I have two likelihood functions $L_{1}(N; M)$ and $L_{2}(N; C)$. Both those likelihoods are functions of the same parameter $N$. However, their expressions are different, as the data $M$ are finer more informative version of data $C$, i.e. from data $M$ I can go to data $C$ but not the opposite.

I work on a Bayesian framework so I use the same prior for both the likelihood functions which is denoted as $N\sim f(N)$

---

What I would like to know is, if there is a way to quantify the $\textit{evidence}$ or $\textit{information}$ or $\textit{impact}$ of the likelihoods with the ultimate goal to argue which likelihood function contributes more into the Bayesian inference.

What I've thought so far,

1. Measure the distance between the posterior $p_{1}(N|M)$, and $f(N)$ and compare it with the distance between $p_{2}(N|C)$ and $f(N)$. The larger the distance the larger the contribution of the likelihood, so the larger the information held into the likelihood.
2. Because $M$ is a more informative data representation compared to $C$ maybe I should take the distance between $p_{1}(N|M)$ and $p_{2}(N|C)$ and see if it is significant. If there it is, then it would mean that the information held in $L_{1}(N;M)$ is larger to $L_{2}(N;C)$

---

Are there any papers that try to do a similar inference, or compare likelihoods information contribution to a Bayesian framework??

Comment: What about looking a the posterior variance ? The smaller the variance, the more informative the model. Or maybe the posterior entropy ?